# With Geometry nodes. How do you select the lowest instance on the z-axis?

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, instances

[image]

I'm trying to create a procedural island, and I need to find the lowest instance on the z-axis with Geometry nodes. In order to start a curve from that point.

Comment: Did you also create the instances with *Geometry Nodes*? I mean: Do you have access to the points used for instantiation?

Comment: Yes, the instances were created with Geometry Nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the points you use for instantiation are available, then you can solve it like this:

[image]

Here I use the node `Attribute Statistics` to determine the lowest value for the Z-axis of all points.

By a subsequent comparison with the Z-positions of the points, the lowest point is marked and is available to you as a selection.

You can then use this selection, for example, to filter out the individual point with `Delete Geometry` or `Separate Geometry`.

In any case, you have several possibilities to process this information. But unfortunately you didn't give away anything specific.

Therefore, if something is unclear, I ask you to complete your question accordingly with further information.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: I knew it had something to do with the "min" on the "Attribute Statistics". That works perfectly for my needs. Thanks.